# how do I use java concurrency while running select querys

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, executor

I have three queries to run all are like "`select * from table`" they are taking so much time.
I want to run all query in parallel using java concurrency, how I achieve this.

Comment: What type of database are you working with?

Comment: Create 3 task classes which implement `Callable` and have query execution as `call()` method body, executor with 3 threads, submit these tasks (you'll get back `Future`s) and get results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap your db calls in a Callable like this:

```
public class SqlTask implements Callable<ResultSet> {

    private String sql;

    public SqlTask(final String sql) {
        this.sql = sql;
    }

    @Override
    public ResultSet call() throws Exception {
        Connection connection = ...; // get connection
        Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
        return stmt.executeQuery(this.sql);
    }
}
```

and then execute them in parralel using an ExecutorService, for example:

```
    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool();
    final Future<ResultSet> futureResult1 = executor.submit (new SqlTask("SELECT * FROM table1"));
    final Future<ResultSet> futureResult2 = executor.submit(new SqlTask("SELECT * FROM table2"));
    final Future<ResultSet> futureResult3 = executor.submit(new SqlTask("SELECT * FROM table3"));
    final ResultSet result1 = futureResult1.get();
    final ResultSet result2 = futureResult2.get();
    final ResultSet result3 = futureResult3.get();
```

Comment: thank you..and how I get three resultset back? I mean how I refer that three resultset?

Comment: Ok, I have added that. Future is a container for some asynchronous results. Then you call get() on it to get the real result (this call might block until the query returns)